# Android code does not start from the main class !

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I'm trying to setup a database using Contentproviders and hit a snag. When I was using debugger to step through the code, it shows that the code runs from the ContentProvider class first rather than the main class ! How is that even possible ? Can anyone help me ? Thanks in advance !

The first code is the main code while the second is the provider class

```
public class MedF1 extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.drug_list); 

    ListView drugListView;
    ArrayAdapter<Drug> aa;
    ArrayList<Drug> drugs = new ArrayList<Drug>();

    drugListView = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.list1);
    DrugProvider.DatabaseHelper mDbHelper1 = new DrugProvider.DatabaseHelper(this);



    //Creation of the Database here
    try {

    mDbHelper1.createDataBase();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {

    throw new Error("Unable to create database");

    }

    try {

    mDbHelper1.openDataBase();

    }catch(SQLException sqle){

    throw sqle;

    }

    //Database created now to fill the view
    int layoutID = android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;
    aa = new ArrayAdapter<Drug>(this, layoutID , drugs);
    drugListView.setAdapter(aa);

    //
    loadDrugsFromProvider();    
}
```

This is the ContentProvider. Debugger shows the first step that is accessed is the "DatabaseHelper" constructor ! Is this normal ? Shouldn't the onCreate method of the main class always come first?

```
 public class DrugProvider extends ContentProvider {

//Variable declaration omitted for brevity.

private static SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

// Creation of the database and its basic parameters
public static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public final Context myContext;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);

        this.myContext = context;

    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if (dbExist) {
            // do nothing
        } else {

            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {

                copyDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each
     * time you open the application.
     * 
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase() {

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            // database does't exist yet.
        }

        if (checkDB != null) {

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just
     * created empty database in the system folder, from where it can be
     * accessed and handled. This is done by transferring byte stream.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        // Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        // Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

        // Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

        if (myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();

        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
```

Comment: DrugProvider.DatabaseHelper mDbHelper1 = new DrugProvider.DatabaseHelper(this); This should make it clear why your DrugProvider gets called... second line in your code. Don't think it's worth more than a comment.

Comment: @Layne: Oh go on...reply as a proper answer, you might get some rep for it.

Comment: Hey layne thanks for replying.  I used that line because I was trying to instantoate the use of the nested class within DrugProvider which is DatabaseHelper. Is there another way of instantiating such nested classes? Where did I get it wrongly? Thanks!

Comment: You didn't do anything wrong, but that's the first thing you're calling so that's why it appeared to you that it was running something other than the class you expected.

Comment: @Jamen your code is fine, it's just in the wrong place.  Move it inside your onCreate method of the activity if you don't want it to execute before the activity is created.

Comment: @all , I've tried to move the code into the onCreate method but the code still starts from the ContentProvider class which is giving me problems. Is there any way i can solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mike had mentioned, move the following line:

```
DrugProvider.DatabaseHelper mDbHelper1 = new DrugProvider.DatabaseHelper(this);
```

into the onCreate() method. LOL I've never answered a question and felt so... unhelpful. Don't know why anyone wouldn't simply make an answer to close this question, but there ya go.

Comment: haha thanks vinay :) well you've helped me figure things out ! i'm grateful ! Thanks !

Comment: @Vinay , I've tried to shift the code into the onCreate method but the code still begins with the ContentProvider rahter than the onCreate method ? How is that so ?

Comment: @jamen You really should lern the difference between declaration and initialization and of course what's going on in both cases. In this context you should also take a look what's going to haben when you initialize for example an arraylist with your <Drug> as data type. Normally I hate these kind of answers since you are asking a proper question for which you want to have an answer. In this particular case I think you should lern this bevor continuing.

Comment: Layne is really spot on. I'm a sucker for helping you out though. :-( So, when you initialize mDbHelper1, you are obviously going fire up the code in DrugProvider because it's all interdependent. That is, follow through the code *systematically*. Start from the top-down. You can see that initializing a DrugProvider object will fire up a lot of other code within the same class. As Layne also suggested, learn what happens when you actually initialize an ArrayList of Drug objects. When you don't understand something, it's very important that you go through the code.

Comment: So, once you figure out exactly what happens when you both initialize the ArrayList of Drug objects and the DrugProvider.DatabaseHelper object, it is now up to you where you want to put those statements within your Activity (so as to fire up the Main activity first), or if you would like to structure the code differently. Clean/readable structural/architectural layout of code is KEY in almost every regard. Once you figure this out, let me know if you're still lost.

Comment: Hi Vinay , Layne : Thank you both for answering my question. I've been quite noobish regarding this so I've been learning on the fly from tutorials on how to create the app hence leading to some problems. I've actually read up a little regarding the declaration and initialization and have thought that they should all fall within the onCreate method of the main class. I've tried run the code again and follow the output of the debugger but still ended up with the code starting with the Content Provider. It runs down from the top till the assigning of Contents - this.myContext = context ,

Comment: before stepping into the main class file onCreate method. I was very puzzled because it was not supposed to do so & I didn't indicate anything special on my manifest. Further down, when the debugger reaches DrugProvider.DatabaseHelper of the main file, the debugger steps back into ContentProvider . It has been very puzzling and thus I tried to recreate a new project with the same basic code and the app worked ... so i'm thinking what could have gone wrong with this code since i don't believe its luck. Is there some sort of "cache" that's "remembering" the previous codes which i need to clear?

Comment: Well it's good that you have it working now! So, what was happening was that you got to the instantiation of the "DrugProvider.DatabaseHelper" part of the main file, and then of course it went into ContentProvider because that's the source class for instantiating that object (i.e. a DatabaseHelper is a class of DrugProvider which extends ContentProvider). Does that make sense? So, after the instantiation, it will resume regular flow at the original Activity.